# Where is std::copy_exception defined?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, language-lawyer

The book *[C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.cplusplusconcurrencyinaction.com/)* by Anthony Williams states in *4.2.4 Saving an exception for the future* that it is possible to store an exception directly without throwing using `std::copy_exception`. However I seem to be unable to find the standard library header where `std::copy_exception` is defined. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**tl;dr**: `std::copy_exception` was renamed to `std::make_exception_ptr` in `<exception>` for the final C++11 standard.

---

The committee decided that the name `copy_exception` (probably copied into  the standard from [`boost::copy_exception`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/exception/doc/copy_exception.html)) was misleading for the following reasons.

The `copy_exception` function returns an `exception_ptr` to a copy of its argument, as if

```
template <class E>
exception_ptr copy_exception(E e) {
    try {
        throw e;
    } catch (...) {
        return current_exception();
    }
}
```

When called with an `exception_ptr` as argument, the function would return another `exception_ptr` pointing to a copy of the `exception_ptr` given as argument, instead of pointing to what the `exception_ptr` argument points to. Because the name `copy_exception` was misleading for this case, the function was renamed to `std::make_exception_ptr` for the final C++11 standard. See the [C++ Standard Library Defect Report 1130](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1130) for details and discussion on this issue.

The `std::make_exception_ptr` function is defined in `<exception>`.