# boost::promise::set_exception() compilation error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I'm getting an error when trying to compile the code below:

```
#include <exception>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    boost::promise<int> pr;

    pr.set_exception(std::copy_exception(std::runtime_error("test")));

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

> error C2668: 'boost::copy_exception' : ambiguous call to overloaded function  d:\projects\boost\boost_1_55_0\boost\thread\future.hpp  2092

I'm using VS2010 and Boost 1.55

For the reference: the implementation of `boost::promise::set_exception' is below:

```
void set_exception(boost::exception_ptr p)
{
    // exception is stored here
}

template <typename E> void set_exception(E ex)
{
    set_exception(copy_exception(ex));  // <- this is the line 2092
}
```

So, there is a template version, which calls non-template version.
I assume in my case template version fails.

The issue disappears when the following code is used:

```
pr.set_exception(boost::copy_exception(std::runtime_error("test")));
```

I.e `boost::copy_exception()` is used instead of `std::copy_exception()`.
Can anyone suggest an option to get code compiled with using `std::copy_exception`?

Comment: I wonder if this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831458/where-is-stdcopy-exception-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; You should use `boost::copy_exception`.

---

`boost::copy_exception` returns a `boost::exception_ptr`, so when we call `set_exception()`, the `set_exception(exception_ptr )` overload is preferred as being a non-template. That call does the right thing.

`std::copy_exception` (now called `std::make_exception_ptr`)  returns a `std::exception_ptr`. This is not the same type as `boost::exception_ptr`, so the function template `set_exception()` is preferred. Instantiating the function template leads to an *unqualified* call to `copy_exception()` within namespace `boost`. That finds:

```
namespace boost {
    template <class T> exception_ptr copy_exception(T const&);
}
```

Since that's just a function, we then do argument-dependent lookup on the associated namespaces of our arguments. The associated namespace of `std::exception_ptr` is `std`, and so we end up also finding:

```
namespace std {
    template <class E> exception_ptr copy_exception(E );
}
```

Neither of those function templates is better than the other, hence the call is ambiguous.

Since there's no advantage of using `std::copy_exception`, and the function doesn't even exist in the standard anyway, use `boost::copy_exception`. It does what you want.

---

Alternatively, you can just use `std::promise`, whose `set_exception()` only has a single overload which takes a `std::exception_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation the reason of ambiguous call